# Doctrine ORM: How to register multiple times on the same table using beginTransaction ()

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, transactions

How do I register in the same database table using the beginTransaction (). Example: Sign several details of a product

```
   $entityManager->getConnection()->beginTransaction();
   try { 
       ...
       // Last Product id registered
       $ultimo_id = $table->getId()

       $num = array(5,2,3);
       $lote = array(8,6,7);

       // The PROBLEM is that only registers the last (in the key case [2]). I did not
       $this->mais_produto($num[0], $lote[0], $ultimo_id);
       $this->mais_produto($num[1], $lote[1], $ultimo_id);
       $this->mais_produto($num[2], $lote[2], $ultimo_id);

       $entityManager->getConnection()->commit();

         return true;
    }

    } catch (\Exception $e) {

        $entityManager->getConnection()->rollback();
        throw $e;
        return false;

    }
```

In mais_produto () function be running the functions of the Doctrine $ entityManager-> persist ($ table); $ entityManager-> flush () to write to the database;

If anyone can help me I will be grateful

Comment: what is the problem? If you're accessing the same object and performing updates over the same columns, it's normal that the last update prevails.

Comment: I wish in a way that everyone was written to not only the last. Believe anyone ever needed to do this, but so far have not found response.

Comment: _It does write everything_: First you update the row with values from key 0. Next you're replacing those values with the ones from key 1. Last you're replacing those values with the ones from key 2.

Comment: So, how can I sign all?

Comment: This link suggested by a colleague helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191139/doctrine2-em-persistentity-on-foreach-loop