# persist multiple entities with Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine, persist

I have pulled out collection of arrays that I need to post in my database. It works.

Now, I need to persist more then one row and I am trying to do it with foreach loop but it doesn't work.

My part of code:

```
$dataset = array();

            foreach ($dataset as $data) {

                $a = new User();

                $a->setFirstName($data[3]);
                $a->setLastName($data[5]);
                $a->setUsername($data[13]);
                $a->setEmail($data[14]);
                $a->setCompany($data[23]);

                $this->em->persist($a);
                $this->em->flush();
 }
```

Comment: You may have a look at this "issue": https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/4422 and some explanation of how doctrine work handles the objects: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191139/doctrine2-em-persistentity-on-foreach-loop

Comment: I have tried it. It doesn't work for me. @BenRoob

Comment: And you have no error ? it just doesn't store the data in your db ? Just to be sure, I guess your `$dataset` is not empty in your real app ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're closing the connection after the flush. Try to load and persist the object inside the foreach loop and then flush outside just one time.

```
$dataset = array();

        foreach ($dataset as $data) {

            $a = new User();

            $a->setFirstName($data[3]);
            $a->setLastName($data[5]);
            $a->setUsername($data[13]);
            $a->setEmail($data[14]);
            $a->setCompany($data[23]);

            $this->em->persist($a);
        }

        $this->em->flush();
```

The EntityManager represents the connection so you just need to flush when you are ready to commit to the DB.